# React shared component using rewired - "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"

Tags: reactjs, shared-libraries, craco, react-app-rewired

I have two create-react-apps in a repo: `shared` and `my-app`.

There is a `shared/src/Test.js` component:

```js
export default function Test(){
    return <div>This is the shared component!!!</div>
}
```

In `my-app` I have installed the following:
`npm install react-app-rewired customize-cra ../shared`

and added

`config-overrides.js`

```js
var path = require ('path');
var fs = require ('fs');
const {
    override,
    addDecoratorsLegacy,
    babelInclude,
    disableEsLint,
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = function (config, env) {
    return Object.assign(config, override(
        disableEsLint(),
        addDecoratorsLegacy(),
        babelInclude([
            path.resolve('src'),
            fs.realpathSync("node_modules/shared/src")
        ])
        )(config, env)
    )
}
```

In `my-app/src/App.js` I `import Test from "shared/src/Test"` and add `<Test />` to the output.

Which when run throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: shared/src/Test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (4:12):
```

Am I missing a step? Is there a simpler way then using react-app-rewired to set up this shared library.

Comment: I suggest you to use `craco` instead of `react-app-rewired`

Comment: @NishargShah checked out craco and looked at their docs and recipes and couldn't find anything that matched my use case. I'd accept an answer using craco if you would like to write one.

Comment: Whats your requirement?

Comment: I want to be able to use components that are in the `shared` app in the `my-app` app.